# Can't break out of some() array method

Tags: javascript, loops, addeventlistener

I got a click event attached to a button to perform a search that checks if a certain element matches a certain condition. In the snippet below there is a some() array method that checks the 'entriesFound' array for the element that matches a certain condition. However everything works find till the else if(el.name !== name.value) condition. The alertbox shows but I need to click the OK button in the alertbox as many times as there are elements in the entriesFound array.

```
import { persons } from './main.js';

export let entriesFound = []

export const searchBtn = document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener('click' , function() {
     let name = document.querySelector('.searchInput')

        if(name.value === "") {
            alert('No search query!')
            return;
        }

        entriesFound.some( el => {
            if(el.name === name.value){
                name.value = ""
                alert("You\'ve already found what you are looking for!")
                el.remove();

            // from here things go wrong

            }else if(el.name !== name.value){
                alert("No data found!")
                return;
            }
        })

        persons.some( el => {
            if(el.name === name.value) {
                addItem(el)
                entriesFound.push(el);
            }
        })
    name.value = ""
    localStorage.setItem('entriesFound', JSON.stringify(entriesFound))
})
```

Comment: Don't think `.some()` is the right method to use in your case. Maybe consider using a simple for loop or for of loop.

Comment: If you want `.some()` to stop prematurely, just return `true` from the callback. But in general, as Yousaf says, `.some()` might not be the best tool to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the return value of some and you can utilize find:

```js
import { persons } from "./main.js";

export let entriesFound = [];

export const searchBtn = document
  .querySelector(".search")
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
    let name = document.querySelector(".searchInput");

    if (name.value === "") {
      alert("No search query!");
      return;
    }

    const entryExists = entriesFound.some((el) => el.name === name.value);

    if (entryExists) {
      name.value = "";
      alert("You've already found what you are looking for!");
      el.remove();

      // from here things go wrong
    } else {
      alert("No data found!");
      return;
    }

    const item = persons.find(el.name === name.value);
    if (item !== null) {
      addItem(item);
      entriesFound.push(item);
    }

    name.value = "";
    localStorage.setItem("entriesFound", JSON.stringify(entriesFound));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you. I combined your solutions. I used regular for loops and the every() array method.

```
import { persons } from "./main.js";

export let entriesFound = [];

export const searchBtn =  
document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener('click' , () => {

    let name = document.querySelector('.searchInput')

    if(name.value === "") {
        alert('No search query!')
        return;
    }

    if(entriesFound.length > 0){
        for(let el of entriesFound){
            if(el.name === name.value) {
                alert('You have found that one already!')
                name.value = ""
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    if(persons.length > 0 ){
        for(let el of persons) {
            if(el.name === name.value) {
                addItem(el)
                entriesFound.push(el)
            }
        }
    }else if(persons.length === 0 ){
        alert('No data!')
        name.value = ""
        return;
    }
    
    
    let noMatch = persons.every( el => el.name !== name.value)
    console.log(noMatch)
    if(noMatch === true){
        alert('No match!');
        name.value = ""
        return;
    }

        name.value = ""
        localStorage.setItem('entriesFound', JSON.stringify(entriesFound))
});
```